# RuntimeError: input must have 3 dimensions, got 2, in my pytorch rnn model

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, pytorch-lightning

[Getting the dimension error, I have sending the data with correct dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb7MZ.png)

Not able to figure where the problem lies in my pytorch lighting rnn model
[Model image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dyys.png)

Comment: The input of an RNN should be three-dimensional (either `(seq_length, batch_size, in_features)` or `(batch_size, seq_length, in_features)` if `batch_first` is set to `True`), yours only has two dimensions. Why exactly are you flattening your input?

Comment: yes I made my data reshape to (1,10,3) the error was gone after that, Thank u for the explanation